# How add database name on error trace

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Is there any way to show in the error trace, info about database name or database ip?

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; 
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused.
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

Note: I´m using springboot, jpa and hibernate.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that your Connection information are corrent, and your JDBC connector in your jar library?

Comment: The FULL STACK TRACE would tell you where that originates. You have omitted it ...